# Is it confirmed that the Hammer of Thunderbolts is intentionally based on Mjolnir?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming, artifacts

In [Viking Mythology](http://www.viking-mythology.com/items.php#sthash.gjKqZd5c.dpuf), Thor has 3 prized possessions: First a hammer, **Mjölnir**. To be able to wield it properly, he must also wear his magical belt **Megingjord** to increase his strength, and his iron gloves, **Járngreipr**, to help him grip the handle.

D&D also has three pieces of equipment which seem to echo Thor's "prized possessions". In D&D 3.5e they appear thus:

1. [Hammer of Thunderbolts](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Hammer_of_Thunderbolts)

   > This +3 Large returning warhammer deals 4d6 points of damage on any hit.
2. [Belt of Giant Strength](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Belt_of_Giant_Strength)

   > This wide belt is made of thick leather and studded with iron.
3. [Gauntlets of Ogre Power](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Gauntlets_of_Ogre_Power)

   > These gauntlets are made of tough leather with iron studs running across the back of the hands and fingers.

I say they echo Thor's equipment since wielding all three produces this effect (found in the Hammer's description):

> [The Hammer of Thunderbolts] gains a total +5 enhancement bonus, allows all belt and gauntlet bonuses to stack (only when using this weapon), and strikes dead any giant upon whom it scores a hit (Fortitude DC 20 negates the death effect but not the damage).

The parallels could be obvious, but **is there a direct reference anywhere (even editions of old) that states that the parallels are intentional?** Are the three D&D artifacts directly inspired by Thor's three artifacts?

Comment: Ruut, to clarify what you are asking: are you looking for explicit linkage that goes from original introduction through each edition's revisions that ends up in Thor's tools as the model in 3.5 -- in terms of the synergy of combining effects even though they aren't the God's actual items?

Comment: After reading the two answers provided, I couldn't help but give both a thumbs up. I didn't really know what the answer to my question would be besides the "yes of course it is." The amount of research and detail is astounding. I didn't get involved in D&D officially until I was in 7th grade, and that was with AD&D 2nd Edition. I wasn't, literally, aware of so much from OD&D and AD&D 1st Edition. I don't exactly know how to clarify my question in a way that would pick one answer over another.

Comment: Perhaps, if there was an "evolution" through the editions that could be shown? I mean, I had the Hammer of Thunderbolts in Baldur's Gate... but that proves nothing and adds nothing, except to show that there was that particular hammer in existence in a video game based on 2nd Edition. Is the Hammer of Thunderbolts the player character version of Mjolnir... I don't know. Is there official artwork of a Hammer of Thunderbolts?

Comment: @Ruut Well, let's talk straight here: You and everyone else are already clear that it's _very, very obvious_ the Hammer of Thunderbolts is _directly and deliberately_ mirroring Mjolnir. I don't think anyone would reasonably imagine the devs, who regularly and liberally steal things from mythology and folk lore, completely and originally came up with precisely one item set that happens to behave _exactly_ like the items of Nordic legend just by coincidence. Official artwork and evolution couldn't make it more obvious than it already is, it is at virtually the maximum obviousness level already.

Comment: Basically the thing that really answers this question in totality is a quote from a dev saying "Yep we modelled that after Mjolnir", and the entire answer could contain just about only that. You're after the devs confirming it, and that's all we need to know. We don't need extra art or hints and so on.

Comment: [Does the idea of Thor throwing Mjolnir have a basis in historical combat?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11737/23547) is apparently a thing we question as to whether it is on-topic.  [Relevant Meta:](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11733/is-this-question-about-throwing-hammers-off-topic-as-a-campaign-research-quest)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Are the three D&D artifacts directly inspired by Thor's three artifacts?

## Yes.

The synergistic relationship was established in Supplement 4 to OD&D (*God, Demi-Gods, and Heroes*, 1976, authors Ward & Kuntz, ed. Kask). This predates AD&D.  Found on pages 23 and 24 is  Thor's equipment that includes:

> **Mjolnir:**
> The magical Hammer of Thor. This hammer, when wielded by the Thunder God, will slay any giant it hits, and it never misses!  Commonly the hammer is thrown and returns to Thor.  Its range is not restricted as is the dwarves' +3 hammer and as long as there is a target in sight the hammer will hit.
>
> When used in any other capacity besides the slaying of giants, the hammer will cause 10-100 points of damage. (snip the description of throwing lightning bolts with 2-24 d8 damage)
>
> **Megingjarder:**
> The magical belt of power.  Combined with his magical gloves these items give Thor the comparable strength of a Storm Giant. When used by itself the belt merely raises the Thunder god's strength to that of a Fire Giant.
>
> **Thor's Magical Gloves of Power**:
> These unnamed items, when worn separately from Megingjarder, give Thor the proportionate power of a Stone Giant.  As mentioned above, when the gloves are worn in concert with Megingjarder, Thor's strength is increased to that of Storm Giant!

Here's the problem: **only Thor can use this hammer.**

> Only beings with a strength equal to a Frost giant may pick up and carry this item of power, (And that at -50% speed) and **only Thor himself may use Mjolnir.**
>
> This hammer, **when wielded by the Thunder God**, will slay any giant it hits, and it never misses! Commonly the hammer is thrown and returns to Thor.
>
> The intensity of the bolt is **controlled by Thor himself**.  Lastly, the hammer shines a light blue color, thus **warning Thor of imminent danger** within 10-60 yards of himself.

What @Nagora cited ([in a most excellent answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/65124/22566)) is that in the 1e DMG, page 168-169, the first example of the *player usable synergistic set* built on this model: hammer, thunder (replaces Thor's lightning with Thor's Thunder, thematic consistency), giant slaying, belt and glove bonuses<sup>1</sup>. The synergy between belt, gloves and hammer mirrors Thor's set in a scaled down model for players to use found in 1e, but it retains an obvious thematic relationship to the God of Thunder:
High strength required
Giant Slaying
Returns to thrower
Thunder effect, stun, replaces 2-24 d8 (!!!) lightning damage of the divine model.

Points from the DMG 1e description:

Hammer of Thunderbolts

> - ...  a regular hammer of largish size and extra weight. It will be to    imbalanced, somehow, to wield properly in combat, unless the
>   character has 18/01 or better strength and a height of over 6'.
> - The hammer then functions as +3 and gains double damage dice an any    hit
> - If the wielder wears any girdle of giant strength and gauntlets of ogre power in addition, he or she may properly wield the weapon if the
>   hammer's true name is known.
> - When swung or hurled it gains a +5, double damage dice, all girdle and gauntlets bonuses, and strikes dead any giant' upon which it
>   scores a hit
> - When hurled and successfully hitting, a great noise as if a clap of thunder broke overhead will resound, stunning all creatures within 3”
>   for 1 round.

The last bullet is strong evidence of the linkage to Thor's hammer from the previous supplement -- Thor is God of Thunder -- as is the strength requirement: scaled down from Storm Giant strength(24) to 18(01) strength as a minimum to wield or swing. (Storm Giant Strength is from DMG page 145 in description of Girdles of Giant Strength).

When AD&D was originally published (1e), the "anti-Monty Hall" PoV expressed by Gygax, Kask, and other TSR worthies informed what came to us in AD&D.

From the Forward to Supplement 4, Tim Kask notes:

> This volume is something else, also: our last attempt to reach the "Monty Hall" DM's. Perhaps now some of the 'giveaway' campaigns will look as foolish as they truly are. This is our last attempt to delineate the absurdity of 40+ level characters. When Odin, the  All-Father has only(?) 300 hit points, who can take a 44th level Lord seriously?

Someone decided that the Thor's set idea was a neat one, but they didn't want mere mortals wielding a god's weapon: that would be too Monty Hall.  Following that reasoning, the linkage between Thor's awesome set scaled down for a player character to use fits like a glove .... if not like an Ogre Gauntlet! :)

Thor's hammer has certain powers when in Thor's hands.
Thor's set adds synergy.
Mere mortals can't make it work, though perhaps a Storm Giant could wield it.
The Hammer of Thunderbolts is something a mortal can use.
A less powerful could be made if you found three independent items.
The template for the synergy is pretty obvious.

An inquiry to Rob Kuntz, Tim Kask, or Jim Ward (or other AD&D contributors) might confirm "of course we modeled it on Thor's item, it was X's idea" but with 40 years gone ... you might not get such an answer.

You might also get "Isn't it obvious?" as an answer.

The team at TSR grew with each passing year as success piled upon success.  Whose idea was it first? Jim Ward's or Bob Kuntz? Someone else's with input to the DMG?
See p. 8 of DMG for a list of contributors:

> Nonetheless, all are herewith credited and thanked, trusting that each
> will know what his or her own contribution was!
> Peter Aronson, Brian Blume, Mike Carr, Sean Cleary, Jean-Louis Fiasson, Ernie (the  well-known Barbarian) Gygax, Luke Gygax, AI Hammock, Neal Healey, Tom Holsinger, Harold Johnson, Timothy Jones, Tim Kask, Rick Krebs, Len Lakofka, Jeff Leason, Steve Marsh, Schar Niebling, Will Niebling, Jon Pickens, Gregory Rihn, John Sapienza, Lawrence Schick, Doug Schwegman, Dennis Sustare, Jack Vance, James M. Ward, Jean Wells, and Skip Williams.

As to the gauntlets and belts:

In Monsters and Treasure, no such synergistic effect is found, nor in Greyhawk.  The first synergy was for Thor's personal items in Supp 4.  The lesser set's synergy arrives in AD&D First Edition (see Nagora's answer).

From Monsters and Treasure, OD&D Vol II, page 38: (OD&D before any supplements).

> **Gauntlets of Ogre Power**: These gauntlets give the wearer the ability to strike as an Ogre and generally give his hands and arms the strength of an ogre. They do not necessarily increase hit probability however.
>
> **Girdle of Giant Strength**: Wearing this device bestows the strength and hit probability (if greater than the wearer's own) of Hill Giant.

Note: Hill Giant Strength isn't enough to handle Thor's hammer, it takes a Storm Giant's strength to do it per supplement 4.

<sup>1</sup> The purse never did match, nor the boots, thanks to fashionistas running amok in Lake Geneva!

Answer (score 10):

From the original text in 1e DMG:

> If the wielder wears any girdle of giant strength and gauntlets
>   of ogre power in addition, he or she may properly wield the weapon if the
>   hammer's true name is known. When swung or hurled it gains a +5,
>   double damage dice, all girdle and gauntlets bonuses, and strikes dead
>   any giant' upon which it scores a hit. When hurled and successfully hitting,
>   a great noise as if a clap of thunder broke overhead will resound, stunning all creatures within 3” for 1 round. Throwing range is 1” + ½”/point of
>   strength bonus for the gauntlets and girdle, i.e. 6 + 7 to 12 = 13 to 18 X
>   ½” = 6½”, 7”, 7½”, 8‘, 8½”, 9”. (Thor would throw the hammer about
>   double the above ranges . . . )

I think the obvious parallel with Thor plus the mention of the god Himself in the text makes it pretty certain that an influence was there.

Thor's personal versions were detailed in Deities and Demigods which gives the various items different powers (the gauntlets grant three attacks per round and are immune to even white-heat).

However, the gauntlets of ogre power and the girdles of giant strength appeared much earlier than any of the AD&D items (they are both from the original 1974 set) and it seems that Gygax made the association when adding the hammer of thunderbolts, rather than it being a pre-planned combination designed as a set from the beginning.

To expand on the range issue. If a user was wearing gauntlets and a girdle of fire giant strength they would have a total damage bonus of +16. half of that is 8, so the throwing range of the hammer would be 1+8=9. This combination is the only way that damage bonuses from the girdle and the gloves can be added together:- 16 damage bonus is huge in 1e.

Other than the fact that Thor is specifically mentioned in the item description, I can't find anywhere where the designer specifically said the words "this is based on Mjolnir" and, since he's dead, we can't ask him any more.

Comment: As someone who is utterly unfamiliar with 1e: What in the nine hells is going on with that range description?

Comment: OK: firstly, distances in 1e are given in inches which means inches as measured by a ruler on the table. Normally one inch represents 10 feet indoors, or 10 yards outdoors. Finally, my cut and paste has screwed it up slightly, so I'll fix that.

Comment: The edit has cleared up a lot, thanks. I had thought that "percent inch" might be a mistake, but you can never really know...